# INSEE API Module not found in PyQGIS

Tags: python, api, pyqgis

I'm a beginner in programming. I made a script that allows me to create and export maps in a full automatize way in PyQGIS. My goal here with this API, is to add some data with the "siret" number on each maps.

But even before I could try to do that, I'm stuck after the installation of this API in a terminal. I'm following this [site](https://pypi.org/project/api-insee/) to help me.

As you can see, installation is fine :

```
C:\Users\Nathan>pip install api-insee
Requirement already satisfied: api-insee in c:\users\nathan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.5)
```

So after that I'm going on PyQGIS, and write the script found in the same site as mentioned before (my consumer and secret keys are fine too) :

```
from api_insee import ApiInsee

api = ApiInsee(
    key = # consummer key,
    secret = # secret key
)
```

And you saw that coming, when I execute it, it's not working. The error message tells me that :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_insee'
```

I'm absolutely don't know why I got this error. So I wonder, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

QGIS ships a python interpreter for itself. It doesn't recognize packages installed via your default python installation.

You seem to be on windows, so one way to install a package would be to find the OSGeo4W shell (`OSGeo4W64.bat`), which is located in the QGIS installation folder. Open it, then execute:

1. `py3_env`
2. `python -m pip install api-insee`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to automatize the production of maps with data coming from SIRENE database which stores data on all French companies, I would advice you to use pynsee python package available on [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pynsee/) since October 2022. Pynsee makes it easy to retrieve data from SIRENE database and provides geographical limits of French administrative areas using IGN API with [pynsee.geodata.get_geodata](https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_data.html#get-geographical-data) function.

It is required to first subscribe to [api.insee.fr](https://api.insee.fr/catalogue/) and to use [pynsee.utils.init_conn](https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html) function to save your credentials.
Then [pynsee.sirene.search_sirene](https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_data.html#search-sirene-data) might help you to download data from insee SIRENE's API.

I made several examples using pynsee and geopandas.

- Insee premises location [here](https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/example_insee_premises_sirene.html)
- General Practioners in Parisian departements [here](https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/example_doctors_idf.html)
- Automotive industry sites [here](https://pynsee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/example_automotive_industry_sirene.html)